# Modify CSS variable in media query

Tags: css, css-variables

Is there a way to **modify** a previously-declared CSS variable inside a media query with just vanilla CSS? What I'm after would look like this (which of course doesn't work as the variables all get computed in the end):

```
#container {
  --elem-size: 20px;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 800px) {
  #container {
    --elem-size: calc(var(--elem-size) * 2);
  }
}
```

I'm aware that it would be possible to declare a "base variable" (e.g. --base-elem-size) and then use it to generate new variable values for different viewports. However, I'm working with a very large number of CSS variables which makes it undesirable to create a duplicate base set out of them. The ideal solution would be able to "modify" a previously-declared value.

Comment: I think the problem you will have is px in calc. If you define 2 var size,--elem-size-small, --elem-size-big, and you use those in your media, it's ok. calc(var(20px * 2), not working

Comment: @pierfarrugia No problem with px at all. Its 20px * 2 = 40px. This works fine. My question is about using the same variable in a re-calculation in a media query.

Comment: Adding variables inside media queries works just fine. I would suggest you use a base variable (like you suggested on you question). It doesn't make your codebase more complicated, on the contrary. If you have a `--font-size-default` and `--font-size-large` variables, which you then assign to `--elem-size: var(--font-size-default)` and `@media-query .... { --elem-size: var(--font-size--large) }` it makes your code much more readable and maintainable. I will add it as an answer as an example

Answer (score 8):

I think having base CSS variables would make your CSS much more readable and easier to maintain, specially if you are working with a big codebase.

May be something like this:

```css
:root {
  /* Define you base variables */
  --font-size-default: 16px;
  --font-size--large: calc(var(--font-size-default) * 1.25);
  /* Assign the base variable to the element variables */
  --elem-size: var(--font-size-default);
}

@media screen and (min-width: 840px) {
   :root {
    /* Change base variable used for element variable */
    --elem-size: var(--font-size--large);
  }
}
```

This allows you to set a base font-size variable and one (or more) "variants" of that variable, which you can then use on your whole project

I would suggest you look into something like the [Open Props](https://open-props.style/) (which has some really great ideas for what base variables can be and how to use them)

Comment: Thanks - As I mentioned in the question, I'm aware of this option and it's a good one. It's just that I'm dealing with 50+ variables in this case and I feel hesitant to declare 50 base vars and then 50 more derived vars.

Comment: you probably won't need to declare s lot of base vars

Answer (score 1):

This might be far from ideal but to some degrees does define the style in one line. It uses fallback values of CSS variables.

Open full screen and change window size to see the result:

```css
:root {
  --elem-size-base: 50px;
}

#container {
  /*  Fallback for base value, optional 2nd fallback for no variable value */
  width: var(--elem-size, var(--elem-size-base, 50px));
  height: var(--elem-size, var(--elem-size-base, 50px));
  outline: 2px solid #000;
  background-color: pink;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  #container {
    /*  This variable for various @media */
    --elem-size: calc(var(--elem-size-base) * 2);
    background-color: lightblue;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
  #container {
    /*  This variable for various @media */
    --elem-size: calc(var(--elem-size-base) * 4);
    background-color: lightgreen;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks - this is a nice solution, same as Boguz's answer. But still relies on declaring both base and actual variables. Trying to find a solution that would not need this as I have a large number of variables.